# Trying to nest dynamically generated JSON based on user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic

I am fairly new at manipulating and writing JSON objects etc and I have this task to dynaimcally create JSON object based on user input. I have managed to create the object at 1 level, but i want to nest objects within objects, this is the desired output

```
// desired output

masterObj = [
  {
    "Market1": {
      "Size1": {
        "id": 1,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size2": {
        "id": 2,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size3": {
        "id": 3,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size4": {
        "id": 4,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size5": {
        "id": 5,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      }
    },
    "Market2": {...},
    "Market3": {...},
    "Market4": {...}

  }
]
```

I am trying to use the push function on my masterObj and then in the for loop push the required objects into the child of the masterObj for each market.  But all i can get to is having all objects on the same level (ie 9 objects), having started going round in circles now trying to solve this...

```
var masterObj = [{

}];

var requested = [
  { 
    "Markets": {
      // boolean values defined by checkboxes
      "Market1": show_m1, "Market2": show_m2, "Market3": show_m3, "Market4": show_m4
      },
    "Sizes": {
      // boolean values defined by checkboxes
      "Size1": show_s1, "Size2": show_s2, "Size3": show_s3, "Size4": show_s4, "Size5": show_s5
    }
  }
]

for (var item of requested) {

  if(item.Markets.Market1 === true ) {
    var m1Obj = {Market1: {}}
    masterObj.push(m1Obj);

    if(item.Sizes.Size1 === true) {
      var s1Obj = {
        Size1: {}
      }
      masterObj.push(s1Obj);
    }
    if(item.Sizes.Size2 === true) {
      var s2Obj = {
        Size2: {}
      }
      sgObj.push(s2Obj);
    }
    if(item.Sizes.Size3 === true) {
      var s3Obj = {
        Size3: {}
      }
      sgObj.push(s3Obj);
    }
    if(item.Sizes.Size4 === true) {
      var s4Obj = {
        Size4: {}
      }
      masterObj.push(s4Obj);
    }
    if(item.Sizes.Size5 === true) {
      var s5Obj = {
        Size5: {}
      }
      masterObj.push(s5Obj);
    }
  }

  if(item.Markets.Market2 === true ) {
    var m2Obj = {
      Market2: {}
    }
    // ouput each requested size
    masterObj.push(m2Obj);
  }
  if(item.Markets.Market3 === true ) {
    var m3Obj = {
      Market3: {}
    }
    // ouput each requested size
    masterObj.push(m3Obj);
  }
  if(item.Markets.Market4 === true ) {
    var m4Obj = {
      Market4: {}
    }
    // ouput each requested size
    masterObj.push(m4Obj);
  }
}

console.log(masterObj);
```

Any help with this would be amazing, In my head i believe I am close to the solution but at the moment its evading me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push won't work because your object has an array of one element.. which is an `object` not an `array`

```
masterObj = [ { ... } ]
```

More than likely you mean to have this kind of a construct:

```
masterObj =   {
    "Market1": {
      "Size1": {
        "id": 1,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size2": {
        "id": 2,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size3": {
        "id": 3,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size4": {
        "id": 4,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      },
      "Size5": {
        "id": 5,
        "reporting_label": "a",
        ...
      }
    },
    "Market2": {...},
    "Market3": {...},
    "Market4": {...}

  }
```

which you can then access with

```
masterObj.Market7 = {...};
```

Or, if you need to access through a variable:

```
key = 'Market7';
masterObj[key] = {...};
```

**EDIT: Note: `JSONS` has nothing to do with this question.  You are dealing with straight objects and arrays. `JSON` applies only when you serialize/deserialize this object into a string -- usually for storage or transport.**

Comment: Thanks will give this a go, the data will become JSON at a later point when i save it to a file but you're correct for now its not JSON :)

Comment: I know I seem a pest for pointing that out, but I've seen too many problems caused by a confusion of JSON vs JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

With a little restructuring this is the code i have ended up with and I am now getting what i needed.

thanks Jeremy for pointing me in the right direction.

```
var requestedMarkets = [
  {market: "Market1", display: show_m1, name: "m1"},
  {market: "Market2", display: show_m2, name: "m2"},
  {market: "Market3", display: show_m3, name: "m3"},
  {market: "Market4", display: show_m4, name: "m4"}
];
var requestedSizes = [
  {display: show_s1, size: '100x200', name: "S1"},
  {display: show_s2, size: '100x300', name: "S2"},
  {display: show_s3,   size: '100x400',  name: "S3"},
  {display: show_s4, size: '100x500',  name: "S4"},
  {display: show_s5, size: '100x600', name: "S5"}
];

for (let item of requestedMarkets) {

  if(item.display === true ) {
    masterObj[item.market] = {};

    for (let size of requestedSizes) {

      var settings = {
        id: uniqueID,
        ...
      }

      if(size.display === true) {
        masterObj[item.market][size.name] = settings;
      }

    }

  }
}

console.log(masterObj);
```